# Change images in a div without refresh in angular

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

how to reload a div content(images) using angular when it has images i.e I have a bunch of values pre populate in the div but when I want to change them, the data is pushed to the  array and I am using $scope.$apply().

Comment: Use `<img ng-src="theUrl" />`

Comment: my question is can we reload a div for the existing or should we use a partial page to show the updated images.

Comment: It is what Angular is about. When changing the data, the view is updated too. What have you tried? (relevant code and html)

Comment: $scope.getSearchByMiles = function() {
   
   
   $http.get('SearchByMiles/', {
          
          params: {
          
          }
}).success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
          
          
          
          var dataAray = [];
          angular.forEach(data, function(item){
      dataAray.push(item);
       
             $scope.search = dataAray;
             
            
             
      });
           $scope.$apply(); 
          
          
          alert("success");
          
         }).error(function(data) {
       
         alert(data);
         });
  }

Comment: <div class="col prdct product-result-item" ng-model="searchDivChange" ng-repeat = "search in filteredPlayers"><!--Products-->
<div class="col-md-3">
<a href="/items/details?id={{search.id}}" class="product-items-link">
<div class="productwrap">
<div class="pr-img">
<!-- <img src="/images/{{search.itemImage}}.jpg" alt="" class="img-responsive"/> -->
</div>
<span class="smalltitle">{{search.itemName}}</span>
<span class="smalldesc">{{search.brand}}</span>
<button class="btn btn-sm btn-primary pull-right">$ {{search.expectedPrice}}</button>
</div>
</a>
</div>
</div>

Comment: In the div there are pre populated values using ng-repeat i need those to change when I call getSearchByMiles function.